# Inception Using LAG() in SQL

Tags: sql, lag, impala

Ok, I've searched this on every where but can not get a solution.

So I have a table like this :

```
member_id public_id
a1        NULL
a1        123
a1        345
a2        612
```

And I want to add a new column, named `conv`. Which is filled with number using this rule :

```
IF PREVIOUSROW(member_id) <> member_id THEN 1
ELSE IF PREVIOUSROW(member_id) = member_id AND PREVIOUSROW(public_id) = NULL
    THEN PREVIOUSROW(THIS_COLUMN) + 1 <-- here is the inception
ELSE 1
```

I know how to access previous row, I can use `LAG()`. But, how to access the previous row from THAT column, which is also using `LAG()` in it.

This is my goal:

```
member_id public_id  conv
a1        NULL       1
a1        NULL       2
a1        NULL       3
a1        123        4
a1        345        1
a2        612        1
```

Thank you for your help!

---

So, after I used your solution, I got result like this :

```
member_id public_id  conv
a1        NULL       1
a1        NULL       2
a1        NULL       2
a1        123        2
a1        345        1
a2        612        1
```

It is because the solution is `conv+1` and `conv` is 1, so the max number will be always 2

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Impala

Answer (score 1):

assuming that you are using impala

```
select 
      member_id
    , public_id
    , case when (prev_member_id = member_id) and  prev_public_id is NULL
            then conv + 1 
            else conv 
      end as conv     
from (    
    select 
          member_id
        , public_id
        , lag(member_id) over( partition by member_id order by public_id asc nulls first) as prev_member_id
        , lag(public_id) over( partition by member_id order by public_id asc nulls first) as prev_public_id
        , 1 as conv 
    from z_test1 
)temp 
order by member_id, public_id asc nulls first;
```

Comment: I was not thinking to make another columns like this. This is work perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: hi @b1n0ys , you got a very smart solution, but it still can not answer my question. I think this is my fault because didn't explain the question correctly. I still need your help :)

Comment: @mthbnd  Query should return the same number of records as the source table. Those 2nd and 3rd record in the result set should not be there.

Comment: did you edit your goal? i don't understand the requirement any more. could you provide more details on what those additional records are. what are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

Lag() accepts an offset so that you can go back more than one record. I don't know the exact syntax for your database, so here's the SQL Server version.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx

Comment: Yes, but I want to access previous row (offset = 1) from _this_ column (`conv` column), which is also using LAG().